# Copy code from binary into new file: new file not executing code

Tags: c, binary, binaryfiles

Question based out of curiosity. Why if I copy the code from a binary compiled from c code, and paste it into a new file that I make executable, this new file doesn't act as a binary and execute the code:

[image]

[image]

I guess there are some sort of metadata, but I don't know how it works.

Comment: Did your "paste" operation copy all the null bytes from the original?  Was the copy identical to the original?  Try `cmp ./test_program ./test_program2`; if there's any output, the files aren't identical and that's a problem.  Yes, the format of executables is very sensitive.  It doesn't make sense to try manipulating them outside of copying whole files, moving files, renaming files or deleting them, or using the compiler tool chain.

Comment: Because if you're copy/pasting with a text editor, you're not creating a binary file, you're creating a text file.  You can't treat a binary file in any other way than as a binary file, and that includes trying to open it in a text editor.

Comment: Please tell us **_exactly_** how you copied the binary file.

Comment: Yes it was that, I copied pasted from a text editor! I thought binary file was so treated as such by the data that was inside it. Thanks!

Comment: when I execute cmp: "./test_program ./test_program2 differ: char 1, line 1"

Comment: I don't really understand how it works.. And I don't find any really detailed explanation of this particular point over the internet. I thought a file was a file period, and what would differentiate a file from another would be the type of data inside that would make it for example interpretable by bash or by the processor itself, or by another application (python or whatever)